# Why does bracket notation seem to access more data then the jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still trying to understand the difference between `$('foo')[0]` and `$('foo').eq(0)`.

As I understand it, the second one should access a jQuery object so I can use jQuery methods without having to wrap it again.

My question is this.  Why does this (using "QuickWatch" in VS) seem to return direct access to the object, meaning that I can instantly access its properties:

```
$(this).children('SPAN')[0]
```

But when I use this, I get access to "prototype", "context", "prevObject", etc. and "[0]":

```
$(this).children('SPAN').eq(0)
```

With the second method, it looks as though I'd still have to use `[0]` to get access to the various properties?

I hope this makes sense, but I am trying to figure out the most elegant syntax.

**Edited: - Not to beat this to death, but I changed the title to make more sense.  The original title was "...are they the same?"  And of course, the two things aren't the same.

Comment: you answered your own question: " the second one should access a JQuery object so I can use JQuery methods without having to wrap it again" jQuery gives access to the elements in it's collection via numerical properties.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Have a look at the sourcecode of `$(…).fn(…)`: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.eq

Comment: FYI, it's called "bracket notation".

Comment: In your case the `children()` returns an array like object where you access the item on index 0 which is a raw DOM node. To get the same effect with `.eq()` (which wraps the DOM node to a jQuery object) you would have to "evaluate it", ie. call `[0]` on it. If you want the same effect as the `children()[0]` call but not do `eq(0)[0]`, use `.get(0)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, all!  Felix, I edited it to "bracket".  limelights, how do I accept your post as the answer?

Comment: @Ellen, this seems like a good question to me (unless someone wishes to propose a duplicate). If it closes, ping me with my at-name and I'll cast a re-open vote.

Comment: For your two examples, do `alert()` on them both, and it will show you what object type each returns. My guess would be that the array syntax will give you a raw DOM element object, whereas the `eq()` will give you a jQuery element object.

Comment: halfer, you are right...that's just what the alert shows.  But that's why it was confusing me...I would think the second method would have been the one to give me access to the properties.  But limelights was right...using get(0) on it does do just what I want.  And with that, the last bit of my control is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the `children()` returns an array like object where you access the item on index 0 which is a raw DOM node.

To get the same effect with `.eq()` (which wraps the DOM node to a jQuery object) you would have to "evaluate it", ie. call `[0]` on it. If you want the same effect as the `children()[0]` call but not do `eq(0)[0]`, use `.get(0)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. `eq()` is a jQuery function. `[]` accesses the array of jQuery objects directly.

One advantage of using `eq()` is it will work defensively.

For example:

```
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
```

If you do `$('li').eq(4).text()` you get nothing. `$('li').eq(-1).text()` gives you 3.

I recommend using `eq()` just to make sure.